# iterate over an array of objects in jade/pugjs

Tags: node.js, pug, keystonejs, jade4j

I have the following json object:

```
 var partners =[{ "name":"partnerx", "image": "imagex" }, { "name": "partnery", "image": "imagey" }]
```

I want to put into a ul object using jade and I tried:

```
ul#slides.swiper-wrapper
   mixin partners(name, image)
    li.swiper-slide
       img(src=#{image} , alt=#{name})
```

This is not working.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this:

```
ul#slides.swiper-wrapper
   each partner in partners
     li.swiper-slide
       img(src=partner.image, alt=partner.name)
```

https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html

Comment: How to iterate over an array of objects in jade/pugjs inside .script ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also access the property using brackets

```
ul#slides.swiper-wrapper   
 each partner in partners
  span #{partner.name}
```